# Continuous displaying data storage from terminal on to a file in Linux

Tags: shell

Temperature sensor readings are continuously displaying on terminal of Linux. Now I need this data to be stored in a file and later use them for my processing.  So how to store data coming from terminal in a file?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the command you use to display the data on the Terminal, then someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use >> to redirect the output to a file. For example, 
`$ ./run.sh >> out.log`

Comment: it my pleasure for a quick response from u...but the output is not from the shell script its from a hardware kit interfaced by using minicom

Comment: @subbaraju: that information needs to be in the question, preferably without us having to prompt you for it.  Whatever command is run on Linux that writes to the terminal will have to be stopped and restarted, and when restarted, you'll have to arrange to redirect the output to a file, either as well as the terminal or instead of the terminal.  You will need to scrutinize the man page for the command (which might be 'minicom', judging from your comment).